# Django rest framework user models permissions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a web app, I need there to be different types of users, Buyer and Seller.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    isBuyer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isSeller = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Buyer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Seller(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I think the models are fine (do let me know if there are better ways). Are the boolean in the User model necessary or is there another way to differentiate between them?

Also since I am using the rest framework I wanted to use permission classes. Something like,

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated, IsSeller])
def deleteProduct(req):
```

How do I make the IsSeller permission class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class IsSeller(IsAuthenticated):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        is_authenticated = super().has_permission(request, view)

        if not is_authenticated:
            return False

        return request.user.isSeller
```

This will check if the user is authenticated and if he is, then it's going to check if the user is a seller so you can only put this class in your `permission_classes` on the view.

Answer (score 0):

First point about your model : if the class Buyer and Seller does not have more fields, it is not needed to have a different class. Working with these models will lead to multiple query to the database : you are trying to reduce these SQL queries to the minimum.

Moreover, if a user is either a buyer or a seller, no need to have 2 booleans. Only one will suffice.
`isSeller = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='By default everyone is a buyer')`

About the permission :

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsASeller(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return bool(request.user
                    and request.user.is_authenticated
                    and request.user.isSeller)
```

and the view can be reduce to:

```
@permission_classes([IsSeller])
def deleteProduct(req):
    ...
```

because a seller is by default authenticated and the permission takes that in account.

Comment: I completely agree, though I think it is more extendable this way (in case need for it ever arise). And thank you for the boolean thing, that helps.